# How to check if any web browser is running, with C++ and WinAPI?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, google-chrome, winapi, firefox

My application has to do some stuff, but first it must know that all web browsers on the computer are shut down (not running).

**How can I determine if they are currently running or not?** I guess there is no common way for all of them, but the solution for all versions of that web browsers will be just fine:

1. Internet Explorer
2. Mozilla Firefox
3. Google Chrome

Of course, after that check, I can show `MessageBox` *"Please close all web browsers before continue"*, I don't have to close them by program (and I don't want to).

I prefer the solution that doesn't use any extra libraries etc., just a basic WinAPI/C++ **if** it's possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179410/check-whether-one-specific-process-is-running-on-windows-with-c check the 1st answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the obvious possibility would be to use `FindWindow` to find whether there's an open (main) window for any of them. For Chrome it looks like you want a class of "Chrome_WidgetWin_1" and for FireFox a class of "MozillaWindowClass" and for IE "IEFrame".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> names{
        "MozillaWindowClass", 
        "IEFrame",  
        "Chrome_WidgetWin_1" 
    };

    for (auto const &name : names) {
        if (NULL != FindWindow(name.c_str(), NULL)) {
            std::cout << "Please close all browsers to continue\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This should be somewhat more dependable than searching for the name of the executable--it's much easier for a user to rename an executable than change the class of main window it creates.

In theory, this (and probably almost anything similar) is open to a race condition: if the user starts up a browser immediately after you've checked for that browser, this could think there was no browser running when there actually was.

Comment: Won't work for IE.  "Internet Explorer_Server" is not a top level window. For IE9, it's "IEFrame".

Comment: @manuell: Oops--corrected (and the same seems to work for IE 10 as well).

Comment: The "not obvious" behaviour is that Chrome_WidgetWin_1 will be find if we run Opera, and MozillaWindowClass for Thunderbird. Except for that, IE/FF/Chrome checks indeed works. P.s. that strange initialisation of vector and for statement "(auto name : names)" are C++ code?

Comment: @PolGraphic: Yes (both are new with C++11).