# Multi-platform way to check if a process is running via the process name

Tags: c++, pid, multiplatform

I'm making a program that will hopefully run on Windows, AppleOS, and GNU/Linux. For the program I need to check if "steamchildmonitor" is running. I know I could do this using ppgrep on linux. But I would rather have one piece of code that runs on all systems. Is this possible, if not what would I use to check if it is running on Windows (I believe the AppleOS implementation would be the same as the linux one). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which programming language? For C++, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179410/check-whether-one-specific-process-is-running-on-windows-with-c

Comment: Yup C++, I'll update the main post. I already checked that post, that one's just for Windows, but I guess it will work if I don't find another answer.

Comment: Process enumeration is platform-specific.  Unless you find a 3rd party library to call the relevant APIs for you, you will have to `#ifdef` your code to call them manually.